# Unable to Get Navigation Drawer Items to Display Items Correctly

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have got a working Navigation drawer in a blank project, however whenever I try to implement the navigation drawer in to an existing project, it doesn't seem to be working properly.

The navigation drawer displays fine, however, when items inside are selected, it doesn't seem to redirect to the fragment selected.

I have tried using many resources, however, I am still unable to progress.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code below:

**NavigationDrawer Class**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;




public class NDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
About.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Home.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Fragment fragment;

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


                }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            fragment = new Home();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.detach(fragment);
            ft.attach(fragment);
            ft.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_rooms) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            fragment = new About();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.detach(fragment);
            ft.attach(fragment);
            ft.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


    }
```

**About Fragment Class**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link About.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link About#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class About extends Fragment {

// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public About() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment About.
 */

public static About newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    About fragment = new About();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_about, container, false);
}


public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        tools:context=".UserActivity">


        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:id="@+id/displayUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listen_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Listen"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/signed_in_header" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked" />


        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
            android:text="@string/sign_out"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/displayUsername2"
            android:layout_width="242dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_nav"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_nav_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**activity_nav_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

+6   <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:checked="true"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rooms"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_room_black"
        android:title="All Rooms" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_box_black"
        android:title="Account" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black"
        android:title="Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help_black"
        android:title="Help" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_about"
        android:title="About" />

     <item
         android:id="@+id/nav_signout"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_input_black"
         android:title="Logout" />
</group>

</menu>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".NDrawer"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_nav">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**app_bar_nav.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="aviraj.firebaseapp.NDrawer">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

But in all honesty - have one more try at this and implement the navigation drawer class from scratch from a template class and put our other main clases in method by method to see any possible conflicts.